# how should i add objects to my vector in C?

Tags: c, pointers, vector

commodity_list which you'll see in places of the code below, is a vector of type item, and type item has 2 vectors, one of type buyer and the other, seller. so basically what's happening is possibly that they are all sharing memory of the local object here. obviously a copy constructor in C isnt possible..so how should i approach this? btw..vector has member "void** obj". i know this would be better in C++ but i dont have that luxury

```
  if(b->location->commodity != NULL){


            trader s;
            s.store = b->location; 
            s.distance = i;  

            int index = search_items(commodity_list, b->location->commodity->name);

            if(index == -1){ //this is a new commodity, not found in commodity list

                item it; //create a new commodity in list
                v_init(&it.sellers);
                v_init(&it.buyers); 
                it.name = b->location->commodity->name; 

                if(b->location->type == LOCATION_SELLER){
                    v_add(&it.sellers, &s); //add buyer/seller to list of patrons in said commodity
                } else {
                    v_add(&it.buyers, &s); 
                }

                v_add(commodity_list, &it); // add commodity to list of commodities

            } else { //add seller/buyer to existing item in the commodity list

                item* it = ((item*)v_get(commodity_list, index)); 

                if(b->location->type == LOCATION_SELLER){
                    v_add(&it->sellers, &s);
                } else {
                    v_add(&it->buyers, &s);
                } 
            }
        }
```

Comment: why not declare a void ** instead of void *obj in your vector implementation ?

Comment: sorry it is void**

Comment: any idea on how i should add stuff to it so the memory doesnt get lost?

Comment: Aaah ok ! You have to malloc your items who need to be inserted in your vector instead of passing by address.

Comment: can i get a small code example? would the malloc-ing be inside the v_add method, and if so, where would i set the member variables beforehand?

Comment: EDIT [Try it] (https://pastebin.com/pfeLmAGD)
You don't need to malloc inside your v_add function.

Comment: I'm going to edit my answer and please validate it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C, there is no official concept of reference like in C++.

You are trying to insert objects that are not allocated dynamically. So the object is automatically destroyed at the end of the function's scope.

So you have to `malloc` your principal `item` and `trader` object to store them anywhere in the program, and so in your list.

[See there](http://pastebin.com/pfeLmAGD)